# Plot dataframe grouped by one column, and hue by another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have the following [DataFrame](https://gist.github.com/silviutofan92/5a6ec2b82931831e164f81613ba76903) and would like to create separate line graphs (1 for each "Cluster"), where x-axis is "Week", y-axis is "Slot Request" and hue is "Group".

To get the data that I want to plot, I use

```
summed = full_df.groupby(["Group", "Cluster", "Week"])["Slot Request"].sum()
```

The snippet above returns a ["Slot Request", dtype = int64](https://gyazo.com/55e6f16264aaf4ea65a4c72f26221d5a). From here onwards, I'm kind-of stuck.

Since I had no success in plotting the result from above, I tried exporting it as a .csv and then re-importing (to bring it back to a dataframe, as I didn't know how else to do it, sorry for the blasphemy).

The only working code I could come up with is below, but that's not exactly what I need to get. No luck using FacetGrid either.

```
for i, group in summed.groupby("Cluster"):
    plt.figure()
    sns.pointplot(data = summed, x="Week", y="Slot Request", hue="Group", scale=0.2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
summed = full_df.groupby(["Group", "Cluster", "Week"])["Slot Request"].sum().reset_index() #reset_index turns this back into a normal dataframe
g = sns.FacetGrid(summed, col="Group") #create a new grid for each "Group"
g.map(sns.pointplot, 'Week', 'Slot Request') #map a pointplot to each group where X is Week and Y is slot request
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. I slightly adapted it, and added it to a new answer, however, would appreciate followup feedback regarding x_axis and colour legend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Sam for the idea. I would've posted in comments, but code formatting was not clear.

Using the following:

```
summed = full_df.groupby(["Group", "Cluster", "Week"])["Slot Request"].sum().reset_index()
g = sns.FacetGrid(summed, row ="Cluster", hue = "Cluster", sharex = False)
g.map(sns.pointplot, "Week", "Slot Request", "Group", scale=0.2, palette = sns.color_palette("muted"))
g.set(xticks = np.arange(1, number_of_weeks+2,week_span))
g.set_xticklabels([w for w in range(1, number_of_weeks+2, week_span)])
```

I managed to obtain: 
[image]

However, I'm not sure hot to set x_ticks and x_tick_labels for all the 3 plots, nor how to add a legend for the colours (where each colour is a different "Group"). Any suggestions?